# Dynamically set the width of a column in full calendar vertical resource view

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Is it possible to dynamically set the width of the columns in full calendar vertical resource view?

Comment: If it is possible to do it statically, probably yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not change the actual cell width but because they stretch to fit the width of the entire scheduler, if you change the min-width of the entire scheduler you can make the cells change width.

I did this in viewRender

```
$("#schedule_container").css('min-width',$('.fc-resource-cell').length*125);
```

and eventAfterAllRender

```
$('.fc-agendaDay-button').click(function(){$("#schedule_container").css('min-width',$('.fc-resource-cell').length*125);});
```

This makes all of the text fit within each cell. The 125 was found after some testing to find a good size for me. You can play with that to have each one be wider or narrower

Answer (score 1):

I just set #calendar width in css.

so if I have html code like this:

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

I use css like this:

```
#content
{
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

#calendar
{
    width: 3000px;
}
```

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47033479/1546049) a better way to do it. Doing so, the toolbar does not resize with the calendar.